# How to do smoething when all the async functions completed which are called through for loop?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, puppeteer, es6-promise

So I am working with `puppeteer` and I am just **scraping** pages in multiple tabs parallelly and to open multiple tabs with the same URL I am using for loop like this:

```js
const startScraping = async (url) => {

    for (let i of MyArray) {
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        page.goto(url).then(() => {
            scrapePage(page); // This is the function where I am scraping through this page. and 
                             // This is also a async function
        });
    }
 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        resolve("Done");
        reject("Error");

    });

}

startScraping(url).then((data) => {

  console.log(data);

})
```

But the problem is that the promise is returned immediately after the loop but what I want is that this `promise` should be returned after all the pages have been **scraped**.

Can somebody help me?

```
PS: scrapePage() is also a async function
```

Thanks in advance.

JUST FOR EXPLAINING SCENARIO:

```js
async function func() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        return "Done";
    }, 3000);
}

async function scrapeSingle(url) {
    return [url, await func()];
}

let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const parallelScrapes = myArray.map((url) => scrapeSingle(url));
Promise.all(parallelScrapes).then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Here I want to print `[[1, "Done"], [2, "Done"], [3, "Done"], [4, "Done"], [5, "Done"]]` after 3 sec but it is printing `[[ 1, undefined ], [ 2, undefined ], [ 3, undefined ], [ 4, undefined ], [ 5, undefined ]]` just immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked.

```js
const startScraping = async (url) => {

    let tasks = [];

    for (let i of MyArray) {
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.goto(url);

        tasks.push(scrapePage(page))
    }

    await Promise.all(tasks);
 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        resolve("Done");
        reject("Error");

    });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing and matching `async` and `then` and even `new Promise()`.

The serial solution would be

```
const startScraping = async (url) => {
  const data = [];
  for (let i of MyArray) {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    const result = await scrapePage(page);
    data.push([i, result]);
  }
  return data;
};

startScraping(url).then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

To do all urls in `myArray` in parallel, you'd want to use `Promise.all()`:

```
async function scrapeSingle(browser, url) {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  return [url, await scrapePage(page)];
}

const parallelScrapes = myArray.map((url) =>
  scrapeSingle(browser, url),
);
Promise.all(parallelScrapes).then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but this is not working as I want. Here as soon as All the tabs are opened `console.log(data)` is called. But what I want this should be done when all the scrapping is done from all the pages.

Comment: My bad, just a sec... Okay, added the missing `await` :)

Comment: Even this is not working. Please consider "JUST FOR EXPLAINING SCENARIO" in the above question, this is what happening.